# Node C++ Addon - How do I access a Typed Array (Float32Array) when it's been passed as an argument?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'd like to make use of the V8 Float32Array data structure. How can I initialise it?

I'd also be interested in direct memory access to the data. How could that be done?

Comment: I have based my attempt so far on: http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html. 

`void ReadTypedArray(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    cout << "args.length " << (args.Length());
}` And I'm having trouble formatting the comment on stackoverflow because when I press return it saves the comment.

Comment: Previously I have read node buffers as char arrays using `unsigned char* jpeg_input_buffer = (unsigned char*)Buffer::Data(arg0);`

Comment: do you use node or pure v8?

Comment: I'm calling C++ code, using node. I am `using namespace v8;`, and I have `#include <node.h>`

Comment: I just tried `Float32Array arr = args[0]->Float32ArrayValue();`. It did not work.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated**

The best way now is to use the helper [`Nan::TypedArrayContents`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/v8_misc.md#api_nan_typedarray_contents).

```
assert(args[i]->IsFloat32Array());
Local<Float32Array> myarr = args[i].As<Float32Array>();
Nan::TypedArrayContents<float> dest(myarr);
// Now use dest, e.g. (*dest)[0]
```

There's a good example of this in [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/b470ce81aabe2a78d7cdd53143de2bee46b966a7/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc#L764).

---

*Original Answer, which shows why the helper is useful*

The v8 API is changing rapidly right now so this depends on your version of node/io.js. To access the data from the array provided as an argument, this should work for node 0.12 through io.js <3.0:

```
assert(args[i]->IsFloat32Array()); // These type-check methods are available.
Local<Float32Array> myarr = args[i].As<Float32Array>();
void* dataPtr = myarr->GetIndexedPropertiesExternalArrayData();
```

In io.js >=3.0 (v8 4.3) you should instead use `ArrayBuffer::GetContents`. (I haven't used this yet and will update this when 3.0 is released.) Docs are [here](http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_array_buffer.html#acd2e6bfb9068ba3a692162f312c47154).

In node 0.10, TypedArrays were home-brewed. This was one way of doing it:

```
Local<Object> buffer = args[i]->Get(NanNew("buffer"))->ToObject();
void* dataPtr = buffer->GetPointerFromInternalField(0);
```

Constructing a typed array can be done with:

```
 Float32Array::New(ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), size * 4), 0, size);
```

Comment: Where does float32_t come from?

Comment: Oops, not sure :). Should just have said `float`, fixed.

Comment: Using the updated example with `dest(myarr);` works for me, thank you. Is the dest object a void* type? char* type? I would like to use std::sort() with this dest object