# Accessing ArrayBufferView's data

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

In a Node.JS Addon I want to process data from a `Buffer` (`ArrayBufferView`) I have this experimental code in C++:

```
void foo(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    auto *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    auto data = args[3];

    if (data->IsArrayBufferView()) {
        auto arrbufview = Local<v8::ArrayBufferView>::Cast(data);
        if (!arrbufview->HasBuffer()) {
            // empty
            return;
        }
        auto content = arrbufview->Buffer()->GetContents();

        std::cout << content.Data()) << "\n\n" << content.ByteLength() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Now I run this code with a script like

```
foo(new Buffer("foobar"))
```

And the data buffer doesn't point to a memoery region containing the `foobar` I put in, but some random other area with a length of 8192 bytes. How do I get to the right data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585387/node-c-addon-how-do-i-access-a-typed-array-float32array-when-its-beenn-pa