# How to read/write data to ArrayBuffer from C++ Node.js addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, arraybuffer, node.js-addon

In short, I have an addon that completes an operation which results in a `uint8_t` array. I need to convert this array and its contents to an `ArrayBuffer`, and return that.

Conversely, the addon can also accept an `ArrayBuffer` as input, and I need to convert that, along with its contents, into a `uint8_t` array.

I am having trouble finding clear documentation on how to do so. I am new to Node, v8, addons, etc. If someone knows how to do this and could help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to be working with a `Uint8Array` instead of an `ArrayBuffer`, but ...

To make an `ArrayBuffer` from an existing block of memory:

```
// given void* data
v8::Local<v8::ArrayBuffer> ab = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(
    Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, byte_length, ArrayBufferCreationMode::kInternalized)
```

[Docs are here.](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-6.10/d5/d6e/classv8_1_1_array_buffer.html#a98c19b0bf91cc3ea22371fbab5707e25) The final argument controls if the memory block will be `free`'d by v8 when the ArrayBuffer is GC'ed. If you use `kInternalized`, the memory must be freeable with `free`.

To get the memory backing an `ArrayBuffer`, use [`ab->GetContents()`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-6.10/d5/d6e/classv8_1_1_array_buffer.html#a0c5f199b812ace46b60bc1bbecad36cd). That returns a [Contents](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-6.10/d7/d34/classv8_1_1_array_buffer_1_1_contents.html) class instance, which has a `void* Data()` method.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31712512/1218408 for some additional examples.

Comment: You're right in that Uint8Array would be preferred, but for this particular implementation, it was specified my program must return an ArrayBuffer.

As for the rest, I did end up figuring it out, but the kInternalized was new to me. Thank you.

Comment: I trie to use ArrayBufferCreationMode::kInternalized. But an exception is raised.